# I am curious about the script that is called on the screen of multiple ".shp" files

Tags: scripting

I'm curious about the script that loads multiple ".shp" files from a folder into a blender scene.

```
import bpy
import os

# Set the directory containing the Shapefiles
directory = r"E:\project\wonju\gdb\tint"

# Iterate through the files in the directory
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    # Check if the file is a Shapefile
    if file.endswith(".shp"):
        # Import the Shapefile
        bpy.ops.importgis.shapefile(filepath=os.path.join(directory, file))
```

Comment: Hello ! It looks like this has been generated by an AI tool, right ? From a quick glance over the internet you want to install the blendergis addon to import a shape file. https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS

Comment: I have several ".shp" and want to call them in python.